# CSS transition on a selector following :hover

Tags: css-transitions

I have a basic overlay like this:

```
<div class="wrap">
  <div class="overlay"></div>
</div>

.wrap {
  position:relative;
}
.overlay {
  position:absolute;
  top:0; left:0; bottom:0; right:0;
  display:none;
}
.wrap:hover .overlay {
  display:block;
}
```

I want to put a

```
.??? {
    transition: all .3s ease-in;
}
```

to ease in the overlay display. Is it possible to use a css transition when you have a pseudo element bound to the hover on an earlier element in the selector chain that displays an element later in the selector chain? (.wrap:hover .overlay)  If so, for what selector? I can't get the overlay nor any of its children to pick up the transition. Can't use js here. I tried the transition on both the .wrap and the .overlay, and on children in the .overlay.

Comment: you can not transition from display: none to display:block.

Comment: Ah, thanks Vals. There's my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The comment from Vals is right. That is, **you can't animate** a transition from `display:none` to `display:block`.

Nevertheless, this doesn't mean that you can't visually create the effect.  There are a couple of ways to achieve this, but the simplest way (based on your markup) is to transition your overlay div from `opacity:0` to `opacity:1` on hover, as demonstrated in the snippet below:

```css
.wrap {
  position:relative;
  height:100px;
  width:100px;
  background:red;
}
.overlay {
  position:absolute;
  top:0; left:0; bottom:0; right:0;  
  height:100px;
  width:100px;
  background:blue;
  transition: all .3s ease-in;
  
  opacity:0; /*hide the overlay by default */
}
.wrap:hover .overlay {
  opacity:1; /*show the overlay */
```

```html
<div class="wrap">
  <div class="overlay"></div>
</div>
```